# Edge browser freezes while selecting files for uploading if directory contains more than 768 files

Tags: javascript, webkit, microsoft-edge

I have a web application which allows the user to upload DICOM and Non-DICOM files. I am using JavaScript, HTML5, Webkitdirectory, and Datatable to populate selected files on UI. The issue i am facing is -

If the folder contains more than 768 DCM files (to be precise), Edge browser freezes and user cannot perform any operations until user hits 'recover this page' button. The size of the DCM file and number studies do not matter.

> Few observations :
>
> - Reading 1
>
> Total Number of Studies: 4, Total Number of DCM files: 768, Total size
>   of the folder: ~500 MB, Time to display on UI: 40 Seconds
>
> - Reading 2
>
> Total Number of Studies: 5, Total Number of DCM files: 769, Total size
>   of the folder: ~500 MB, Time to display on UI: **Browser Freezes**
>
> - Reading 3
>
> Total Number of Studies: 2, Total Number of DCM files: 768, Total size
>   of the folder: ~30 MB, Time to display on UI: 40 Seconds
>
> - Reading 4
>
> Total Number of Studies: 3, Total Number of DCM files: 769, Total size
>   of the folder: ~30 MB, Time to display on UI: **Browser Freezes**.
>
> ***Note : This work like a charm in Chrome And Firefox.***

Here is my code which is executed for each and every DICOM file (Inside forEach) -

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = function(evt){
    console.log("Completed Reading");
    var arrayBuffer = fileReader.result;

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    _parseDicom(byteArray);
    try {
        if (fileReader.readyState !== 2) {
            fileReader.abort();
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('error occured: '+err);
    }
}
var blob = f.slice(0, 50000);
console.log("Starting to Read");
fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Analysis :

- Edge browser freezes after logging "*Starting to Read*" 20-25 times, whereas "*Completed Reading*" is never logged.
- I tried to check if browser works efficiently if we reduce the load on browser by adding some delay after reading a sub-set of files.
  So that it can start processing few files and user can see some progress. But this also doesn't seem to work as per expectations.Eventually this behavior affects the total time required to render all files on UI.
- I tried looking into DICOMDIR file, but it does not include all information that we display in the study grid, such as body parts, institution name, referring physician name also image UID, image frames are missing. To fetch this stuff, we need to parse each and every DICOM file for each study to retrieve the missing information.m For reading file, we need access to user's file system to retrieve full path of file. But this is not feasible due JavaScript, JQuery security reasons.

> I believe this may be due to browser memory or function call stack as
>   `readAsArrayBuffer` would generate onload event once it finishes
>   reading.

Any workaround or any idea if this is an issue with MS Edge browser itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm curios what your `_parseDicom` dose... if it can be optimised to check if some magic number is there to indicate if a file is a DCM file (I don't know what a DCM file is)

Perhaps you shouldn't do all those File reads in a forEach loop since that will read all files in parallel, you could maybe optimize the memory if you do one at a time.

```
async function doWork(fileList) {
  for (const file of FileList) {
    const res = new Response(file.slice(0, 50000))
    const arrayBuffer = await res.arrayBuffer()
    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
    _parseDicom(byteArray)
  }
}
```

Perhaps something that would be better is if your _parseDicom could accept a stream instead of a byte array

```
async function doWork(fileList) {
  for (const file of fileList) {
    const res = new Response(file.slice(0, 50000))
    const stream = res.body.getReader()
    await _parseDicom(stream)
  }
}
```

The other best thing could be to move this into a web worker and postMessage the file to it

### es5 solution

```
function doWork(files) {
  var file = files.pop()
  file && new Response(file.slice(0, 50000)).arrayBuffer(function(arrayBuffer){
     var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)
     _parseDicom(byteArray)
     doWork(files)
  })
}

doWork(Array.from(fileList))
```

Comment: A DCM file is an image file saved in the Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine (DICOM) image format. It stores a medical image, such as a CT scan or ultrasound. DCM files may also include patient information to pair the image with the patient. Also, I am using dicomParser to retrieve information from file. I don't see any method or way that this library accepts stream instead of byte array.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I would check and get back to you.

Comment: Your solution to use _async-await_ does resolve browser freezing issue but it does hinder the performance. It does increase the performance time both of Edge and Chrome. Using recursion increases performance time drastically. Hence I am gonna use the normal _async-await_ approach. 

Thanks, for the help..

Comment: Marking this as answer as it resolves the major issue of Edge Browser Freezing. With the note that it hinders the performance..

Comment: you can increase the concurrency with something like: `arr = Array.from(fileList); doWork(arr); doWork(arr)`

Comment: Instead of creating an array from object. I am using `[].forEach.call()` and passing object and function which would internally call `doWork()`